# Removing pulseaudio, about ALSAMixer

Tags: 10.10, kubuntu, alsa

I removed pulseaudio today because rosetta stone had conflicts identifying the microphone which kinda makes it useless to me to learn a new language. Thing is, Alsamixer seems to have screwed up so I'm not really familiar on which configuration file I have to tweak to make the whole system use alsamixer (actually it does... but the problem is this error)

```
$ alsamixer 
ALSA lib pulse.c:229:(pulse_connect) PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Connection refused

cannot open mixer: Connection refused
```

Could anyone enlighten me on which configuration file I have to change?

Comment: Uhh, I would install Pulseaudio again with `pavucontrol` as well. You might have more success with configuring your microphone then.

Comment: It seems like... there's a problem with WINE and ... all the configuration... ... need to search deeper... I'll try that out later

Comment: I would install libasound2 package, for instance and alsa/alsamixer full package... If you deleted Pulseaudio, you don't need libpulse...

Comment: This question appears to be abandonded, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that.

Answer (score 2):

I've deleted PulseAudio too, because is the only way for me to put the mic working on skype...

I don't know why skype doesn't work well with Pulseaudio, but it works for me delete Pulseaudio and full installed Alsamixer Package.

You may want to try that. As i said before, maybe you don't need *libpulse* if you don't have pulseaudio... perhaps you should get *libasound2* package for Alsamixer. It works for me and my Skype connection works great and my music too. Hope i helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall pulseaudio then run Rosetta using `pasuspender`