# How do I replace Pulseaudio?

Tags: 11.04, pulseaudio, alsa, oss

Previous answers refer to previous versions of Ubuntu.

I'm having the same issues and dislikes with Pulseaudio in Natty as I had with previous versions of Ubuntu, so I want to replace it with something else.

I'm looking for references to step-by-step instructions by someone that succeeded in the replacement. ALSA or OSS are fine.

I don't care about the loss of integration, because it can be patched. I just want the (for me) ill-behaved pulseaudio out of my system.

Answer (score 2):

I just went ahead and apt-get removed pulseaudio. Sound worked fine where it matters:

- System events
- Banshee
- Skype

To regain sound control from my keyboard, I installed [AutoKey](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/autokey-gtk), and attached the following scripts to the corresponding keyboard keys:

```
#Volume Down
from subprocess import call
call('amixer set PCM 2dB-'.split())
```

and

```
#Volume Up
from subprocess import call
call('amixer set PCM 2dB+'.split())
```

and

```
#Mute-Unmute
from subprocess import call
call('amixer set PCM toggle'.split())
```

Answer (score 1):

I've faced the same issue and have erased pulseaudio full package as well. Then i've installed AlsaMixer full package. you can look for it on synaptic.

When you erase pulseaudio on synaptic, other dependencies would be necessary to erase as well, like Ubuntu-desktop. That will erase sound icon on the tray.

To resolve this, you will have to install AlsaMixer, then put the AlsaMixer icon on the unity panel to control your sound board easily.

[Removing Pulseaudio and installing Alsamixer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30389/removing-pulseaudio-about-alsamixer/47896#47896)

Hope this will help you.